# Trying to do a flexible/generic minimum distance level of detail distance ranges system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid

Well, I'll like to create a level of detail system for my game to load the terrain.

The point here is that I'll like to use the minimum expression for distances, so all the chunks that I load match at the corners but there are no redundant parts, like here:

[image: ...]

So, more something like this:

[image: ...]

The purpose here is to have the maximum render distance with the minimum count of gameobjects to load.

I have two main concerns the system is not flexible for initial minimum distances that are non-base of 2.

As something like this is browsed:

[image: ...]

Another thing is that distance must be patched:

```
                    //// If the number is even, then we must do this patch
                    if (currentDistanceLevel == 128)
                        sum += currentDistanceLevel / 2; // TODO, why?
```

I don't understand why...

This is what happens:

[image: ...]

This is my code:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Calculate the the minimum distances between level of detail chunks.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lodLevels">The number of lod levels to go into.</param>
        /// <param name="numberOfChunks">The number of chunks after the view distance from the ChunkGenerator system finishes.</param>
        /// <returns>A list of distances to use on a grid of level of detail. (See https://i.gyazo.com/0ceb8ff3a4ebab8391532892fc8b6f82.png)</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<float> CalculateOptimumLoDValues(int lodLevels, int numberOfChunks, int chunkSize)
        {
            var back = false;
            var sum = 0;
            var currentDistanceLevel = chunkSize;
            for (var l = 1; l < lodLevels; l++)
            {
                // The last step is give the previous sum
                yield return sum;

                // At the second step, if we didn't went to the previous level
                if (!back)
                {
                    // We half the number of chunks of the previous level
                    numberOfChunks /= 2;

                    // And we double distance for the next level
                    currentDistanceLevel *= 2;
                }
                else
                    back = false;

                numberOfChunks += 2;

                // First, if we want to avoid this effect, we must do the following step.
                // https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nfgd.png
                // at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72636128/trying-to-position-all-chunks-for-distinct-lod-levels
                // ----------------
                // If the following distance level has an odd number of elements then I try to match the current row/column by doubling it, in that way non of the following corner will be half of the previous one.
                // The number of chunk on the rows goes, 16-10(8+2)-12(10+2)-8(12/2+2)-6(8/2+2)-8(12/2+2)-6(12/2+2)....
                if (numberOfChunks / 2 % 2 != 0)
                {
                    // Then, if the number is odd after summing the two corners and dividing it,
                    // we must go into he back level, set the flag to true and sum the distance
                    l--;
                    back = true;

                    sum += currentDistanceLevel * 3 / 4;
                }
                else
                {
                    //// If the number is even, then we must do this patch
                    if (currentDistanceLevel == 128)
                        sum += currentDistanceLevel / 2; // TODO, why?
                    else
                        sum += currentDistanceLevel; // For the rest of the levels we sum it
                }
            }
        }
```